# Interpolate line and locate point on line with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, html, request

I want to make a location tool in a leaflet web map.

In fact, I create a wep map application with Leaflet in which we can find those layers:

- Bing aerial layer
- POI = Points layer which contains geographical coordinates and kilometer point of a line
- Lines = Polylines layer

My lines were built and calibrated with ArcGIS in ESRI shapes format but for the web application in Leaflet, I transformed this data in a GEOJSON Format.
I don't have a server and GeoJSON is better for the vizualisation in Leaflet.

With those layers, I have to locate some kilometers point on the lines but those points are not in the POI layer. 
For that, I have to make a HTML Form where we put the kilometer point that we are looking for. 
And after, I want the tool gives us the position of this kilometer point on the line and zoom on it on the map.

For that, I found the Leaflet.GeometryUtil functions on Github (Interpolate on line and Locate On line by [makina corpus](http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/index.html)) but I don't know how to use it and how can I make the link between the HTML Form and those javascript functions.

Here's an schematic picture of want I want to do :

[image: html_form_treatment]

Please, can you give me a little help ?

Comment: Someone ? Please ?

Comment: Here's a partial answer.  To get your form input into javascript, try something like this: `document.getElementById('txt_name').value`.  More ideas, e.g. using jQuery, at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088467/get-the-value-in-an-input-text-box).  I also strongly recommend looking at the tutorials for `Leaflet.GeometryUtil`: [tutorial-closest](http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/tutorial-closest.html) and [tutorial-distance-length](http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/tutorial-distance-length.html).